# Problema al querer tomar los datos de un excel y pasarlos a la BBDD

Tags: java, base-de-datos, excel

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para el que me facilitaria mucho tomar los datos desde un excel que esta completo hacia mi base de datos. En este caso estoy usando java para el programa y MySQL para la BBDD. Cuando intento cargarlo me tira este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at
> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.getAttributes(ElementImpl.java:139)    at
> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.getAttributes(ElementImpl.java:139)
> at
> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.synchronizeData(DeferredElementNSImpl.java:123)
> at
> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.getNamespaceURI(ElementNSImpl.java:250)
> at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1420)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
> at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
> at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
> at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1385)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1370)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:370)
> at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:144)
> at
> org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:183)  at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:175)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:438)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:403)
> at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:190)  at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:296)
> at cargarbbdd.cargarBBDD.cargarExcel_BD(cargarBBDD.java:24)     at
> cargarbbdd.cargarBBDD.main(cargarBBDD.java:14) Java Result: 1

Por lo que pude buscar mismo aca, es porque el archivo excede la memoria temporal que usa java para comenzar el programa, pero no entendi bien como poder solucionarlo. Es un proyecto que necesito entregar lo antes posible asi que cualquier respuesta seguro me ayuda. Graciass.

```
package cargarbbdd;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class cargarBBDD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cargarExcel_BD();
    }

    public static void cargarExcel_BD() {
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            Connection conexion = con.getConnection();
            FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\santt\\Desktop\\Alterna\\Base de Datos.xlsx"));
            //hasta aca si ejecuta bien    
            XSSFWorkbook libroLectura = new XSSFWorkbook(archivo);
            System.out.println("error");//ya aca no ejecuta
            XSSFSheet hojaLectura = libroLectura.getSheetAt(0);

            int cantFilas = hojaLectura.getLastRowNum();

            for (int i = 1; i <= cantFilas; i++) {
                Row fila = hojaLectura.getRow(i);

                ps = conexion.prepareStatement("insert into productos (codigo,tipo_Producto,nombreProducto,proveedor,costo,costoConIVA,precioFinal,stock) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, fila.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(2, "");
                ps.setString(3, fila.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(4, "");
                ps.setDouble(5, fila.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setDouble(6, fila.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setDouble(7, fila.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setInt(8, 0);
                ps.executeUpdate();

            }

            conexion.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error, " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Ese es el proceso que utilizo en estos casos. Lo use varias veces y me funciono siempre, pero en este caso el archivo pesa 7mb, asi que no se si eso realmente influye

Answer (score 0):

El error indica el problema:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Definitivamente, es un problema de asignación de memoria, mientras más crezca tu archivo .xlsx, requerirás de más memoria para procesarlo, ya que un documento XSSF requiere bastante memoria, una opción es usar la [biblioteca POI](http://devdoc.net/apache/poi-3.13/download.html) para poder manipular documentos Microsoft, esta tiene mucho mejor manejo de memoria.

**Puedes optimizar, después de abrir el archivo usando la clase [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) es muy importante cerrar el flujo de entrada de archivos y liberar todos los recursos del sistema asociados con el flujo usando el método [.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close--).**

```
    ... 
    ...
    try {
        Connection conexion = con.getConnection();
        FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\santt\\Desktop\\Alterna\\Base de Datos.xlsx"));
        //hasta aca si ejecuta bien    
        XSSFWorkbook libroLectura = new XSSFWorkbook(archivo);
        System.out.println("error");//ya aca no ejecuta
        XSSFSheet hojaLectura = libroLectura.getSheetAt(0);

        int cantFilas = hojaLectura.getLastRowNum();

        for (int i = 1; i <= cantFilas; i++) {
            Row fila = hojaLectura.getRow(i);

            ps = conexion.prepareStatement("insert into productos (codigo,tipo_Producto,nombreProducto,proveedor,costo,costoConIVA,precioFinal,stock) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, fila.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            ps.setString(2, "");
            ps.setString(3, fila.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            ps.setString(4, "");
            ps.setDouble(5, fila.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
            ps.setDouble(6, fila.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
            ps.setDouble(7, fila.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
            ps.setInt(8, 0);
            ps.executeUpdate();

        }

        archivo.close(); //*** Cierra FileInputStream 

        conexion.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error, " + ex);
    }
    ...
    ...
```